# C# | How do I change the namespace in an XML document?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

So im struggling to change the namespace for specific nodes in an XML.

This is what i want to achieve:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.justapage.com/webservices/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:products_Update>
      <ns1:login>
       ...
      </ns1:login>
      <ns1:products>
        <ns1:product>
          ...
        </ns1:product>
      </ns1:products>
    </ns1:products_Update>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But the results always turns out like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.justapage.com/webservices/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:products_Update>
      <SOAP-ENV:login>
       ...
      </SOAP-ENV:login>
      <SOAP-ENV:products>
        <SOAP-ENV:product>
          ...
        </SOAP-ENV:product>
      </SOAP-ENV:products>
    </SOAP-ENV:products_Update>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is how i serialize it:

```
 public static async Task<string> SerializeSendMessage<T>(this T toSerialize)
    {
        string returnString;
       
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
        {
          
            var xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlns.Add("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            xmlns.Add("ns1", "http://www.justapage.com/webservices/");

            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, toSerialize,xmlns);
            returnString = sw.ToString(); // Your XML
        }

        return returnString;
    }
```

The class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope",IsNullable = false)]
    public class ArticleEnvelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body",Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP-ENV")]
        public string SOAPENV { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns1")]
        public string Ns1 { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "products_Update")]
        public ProductsUpdate ProductsUpdate { get; set; }
    }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "products_Update")]
    public class ProductsUpdate
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "login")]
        public Login Login { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "products")]
        public Products Products { get; set; }
    }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "products")]
 public class Products
    {
     
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "product")]
        public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have tried to find some information about this but with no success and I now hope that someone here can point me into the right direction on how to acheive this.

Comment: Well, show us the class of the type T you use and an instance of that class you populate.

Comment: For `[XmlElement(ElementName = "products_Update")]` you rather want to have `[XmlElement(ElementName = "products_Update", Namespace = "http://www.justapage.com/webservices/")]`, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static ArticleEnvelope envelope { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;


            XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArticleEnvelope));
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
            {

                var xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                xmlns.Add("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                xmlns.Add("ns1", "http://www.justapage.com/webservices/");

                xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, envelope, xmlns);
            }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public class ArticleEnvelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "products_Update", Namespace = "http://www.justapage.com/webservices/")]
        public ProductsUpdate ProductsUpdate { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductsUpdate
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "login", Namespace = "http://www.justapage.com/webservices/")]
        public Login Login { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "products", Namespace = "http://www.justapage.com/webservices/")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "product", Namespace = "http://www.justapage.com/webservices/")]
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
    public class Login
    {

    }

    public class Product
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked flawless! Just by adding XmlArray decoration and XmlArrayItem did the job.

Comment: It would not of fixed the namespaces.